# Setting up files for Spline using ArcGIS Pro Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, error-000840, spline

I have converted Polygons to Raster so I can perform a spline, but I cannot get the raster as in input on [Spline](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/spline.htm) without Error 000840. Tracking down other solutions, I tried to "Make Feature Layer" from a .lyr file I made for the Raster, and that too has a Error 000840.

Any ideas on what I'm missing to get it all to fit in the [Spline](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/spline.htm) tool?

Answer (score 2):

Spline interpolation requires point feature class as an input to do interpolation. You can not use polygon or raster (as mentioned in your question) as an input to the spline tool. You need to have point data with z_field (numeric field).